# How can I call other APIs after a user is logged in using CURL?

Tags: php, api, curl, authentication

I'm trying to call a login API in PHP as shown below, but I'm new to using APIs. I would like to know how to manage the session here so I can call other APIs once the user is logged in; so far I'm only able to log in, but I'm unable to call any other API because it says that the user is not logged in.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/Login?username=user&password=1234");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this to store the session / cookie once created.

```
function CURL_R($url, $cookie, $file, $jar)
{
   $c = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
   if ($file == true) {
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
   }
   if ($jar == true) {
      curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
   }
   return curl_exec($c);
   curl_close($c);
}

// ---

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$cookie = $username . '.txt';

$login = CURL_R(
   "http://www.example.com/Login?username={$username}&password={$password}",
   $cookie,
   true,
   true
);

$other_api = CURL_R(
   "http://www.example.com/Other-api",
   $cookie,
   true,
   false
);
```

To use the CURL_R() function the fields are url, cookie path, file and jar. The jar is what stores the cookie / session so after login jar will be false and file will be true to use the cookie on the other API.

Comment: Jake thank you so much it worked that's what I needed your help is much appreciated